# EDIT Add filtered table to ListBox object

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add only the visible rows of a table to a ListObject. However, the code is not functioning properly.

EDIT: Thanks Rory for the correction. The error I get now is code 1004, and the debugger points at "ListBox1.List(I, 1) = y.Range(1)"

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim TagArray As Variant
TagArray = Split(Me.Tag, "-") 'This userform takes the worksheet and table 
name from another userform
Dim x As Variant, y As Range, I As Long
Set x = Worksheets(TagArray(0)).ListObjects(TagArray(1)).Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For Each y In x
        I = y.Row
        ListBox1.List(I, 1) = y.Range(1) 
        ListBox1.List(I, 2) = y.Range(2) 
        ListBox1.List(I, 3) = y.Range(3) 
        ListBox1.List(I, 4) = y.Range(4) 
        ListBox1.List(I, 5) = y.Range(5) 
        ListBox1.List(I, 6) = y.Range(6) 
        ListBox1.List(I, 7) = y.Range(7) 
        ListBox1.List(I, 8) = y.Range(8) 
        ListBox1.List(I, 9) = y.Range(9) 
        ListBox1.List(I, 10) = y.Range(10) 'I could probably use a for loop here. Not critical at this point though.
    Next
End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It's `Listobjects` not `Listobject`

Comment: Thanks @Rory! I missed that one. Now there is a different error though :(

Comment: Use `Cells` instead of `Range`. The syntax is different when you aren't using the `Range` property of a `ListRow`

Comment: No luck with ListBox1.List(I, 1) = y.Cells(1).Value, ListBox1.List(I, 1) = y.Cells(I, 1).Value, or removing the .value